# Backup Exec System State

Tags: backup, backupexec, system-state

Does anybody see any point in backing up System State using 'Backup Exec' when 'Backup Exec System Recovery' is running on a server?

The only good thing i can see coming from it is having the System State backup on tape aswell in an image.
But i can see it bad with VSS clashes...

What do people usually do?

Answer (score 1):

I see the value in it. There may be a case (as rare as it might seem) that you'll want the System State, outside of your image backups. I've restored domain controllers from just the System State many times, without the need for full image backups.